# Ansible run role based on changed status

Tags: linux, ansible

I am calling all the roles in order and now I have to add condition check before running other roles,

Current main.yml

```
- hosts: all
  gather_facts: no
  roles:
     - artifacts_copy
     - app_build
     - db_build
     - log_build
```

artifacts_copy: copies code

Is it possible to add a condition, if  artifacts_copy role changed then run remaining roles otherwise just skip remaining roles

```
  something like this

  roles:
     - artifacts_copy
     when: artifacts_copy.chnaged=true # then run below roles
           - app_build
           - db_build
           - log_build
```

Comment: A module can [return value](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/reference_appendices/common_return_values.html#return-values) e.g. `changed`. A role can't. Use `include_role` or `import_role`.

Answer (score 3):

I just figured it out and it may help others so posting this answer

roles:

```
       - artifacts_copy
       - app_build
       - db_build
       - log_build
```

artifacts_copy: tasks/main.yml added set fact like this

```
---
# tasks file for artifacts
- name: copy artifacts
  copy:
     src: files
     dest: /root/mycode/
  register: artifacts_copy_status

- set_fact:
    artifacts_copy_status={{ artifacts_copy_status }}
```

then I called role like below

```
---
- hosts: all
  gather_facts: no
  roles:
     - artifacts_copy
     - role: app_build
       when: artifacts_copy_status.changed | bool ==  true
     - role: db_build
       when: artifacts_copy_status.changed | bool == true
     - role: log_build
       when: artifacts_copy_status.changed | bool == true
```